# Attributes not available in udev

Tags: udev

I'm attempting to write a udev rule for a USB device, however I'm having trouble matching the `ATTRS{*}` attributes in my rules. After a little debugging using `udevadm info`, I've found that none of my devices are showing any attributes.

When I run `udevadm info -a` for the root volume on my linux server, I get this:

```
  looking at device '/devices/vbd-768/block/xvda':
    KERNEL=="xvda"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{ro}=="0"
    ATTR{size}=="83886080"
    ATTR{stat}=="  717683    43803 15924796   381200  8002096  5757360 169243664  6994333        0   635530  7372343"
    ATTR{range}=="16"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTR{ext_range}=="16"
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"
    ATTR{removable}=="0"
    ATTR{capability}=="10"
```

However, when I run it on my laptop, I get this:

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda':
    KERNEL=="sda"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
```

This occurs for any device. I can't seem to get `ATTR{*}` variables for any device on my system. What might be causing this issue?

Note: I'm running Arch Linux, stock kernel, up to date as of this post.

Comment: Would you post full output `udevadm info -a ...` that shows all parent nodes.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the *exact* same issue, on an rpi.

Comment: Run ` udevadm  monitor -- enviroment --udev` And plug your Stick in.

Comment: Have you rebooted your computer since the last kernel update?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering that you're viewing the correct entry in `udevadm`.

You're accessing `/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda` on the laptop, which is very different from the `/devices/vbd-768/block/xvda` accessed on the server.

If you interest is in disks I would suggest looking it up by bus ID.

---

You can find the disk's bus ID using `lsblk -S`. There should be 7 rows, the first two are all you care about: `NAME` and `HCTL`. `NAME` indicated the drive name (such as `sda`) and `HCTL` indicates the BUS id (such as `2:0:0:0`).

Now use this bus ID when looking up with `udevadm`

`udevadm info --path=/sys/bus/scsi/devices/[bus ID] -a`

---

When I did this one of the output groups was for something like your `/devices/vbd-768/block/xvda`, as well as the `ATTRS`. It seems the path you specify here is only for a subset of the drive's info.